# Issues with iCloud settings when cloning Mac hard drives

Tags: icloud, carbon-copy-cloner

I'm cloning several Mac Minis from an original one. Somehow the iCloud settings get messed up every-time, and I have to go through the following:

1. Logout (it still maintains the username, but I get an empty shell).
2. Login.
3. Go though all the original settings manually.

As I have to do this process multiple times a day, I wonder if there is a way to automate this process, or - best option - fix the problem at the origin, and have the cloning get everything right in the first place.

I am using latest version of Carbon Copy Cloner, and this is a known issue. 
Not sure about SuperDuper!.

It looks like there is a key macOS has a "Local Items" keychain that gets ignored when it's copied to another Mac, and that could be part of the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you de-configure the source Mac Mini from iCloud and clone it again. I'm afraid you'll have to then re-configure iCloud on each Mac you then restore from the cloned image. The keychain system is especially secure, and I'm not surprised this is happening.

Comment: Thanks @IconDaemon this is exactly what I'm doing at the moment hoping I will find some other solution! I hope there is another one, some sudo script or even manual copy and paste of some files!

I have Desktop cloud sync enabled, and it is a pretty long process...